# Allure @Step does not appear in the allure report (Selenide TestNG Gradle Allure)

Tags: java, gradle, testng, allure, selenide

Help solve the following problem:
Test run through the command ./gradlew luma_magento_ui: test
The report is successfully generated, but Step does not appear in the test case.

```
   @Step("registration user")
    public Response registerNewUser(Customer customer) {
        return setup()
                .body(customer)
                .when()
                .post("/rest/V1/customers");
    }
```

build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.franzbecker:gradle-lombok:2.1"
        classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.5"

    }

}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok'
    apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

    test{
        useTestNG()
    }

    allure {
        version = '2.7.0'
        configuration = 'compile'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies{
        compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-testng', version: '2.12.1'
        compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'
    }


}
```

Project - https://github.com/dissid/luma_magento

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar example which is working properly and steps are included in the report. Please take a look at the code:

```
import static io.qameta.allure.Allure.step;

@Test
public void test1_login () throws TestException {

    step("Login to app");
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(super.driver,20);
    loginPage.login();

    step("Open main page");

    step("Logout from the app");

}
```